# how to write select statement inside if in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to write select statement inside if in PostgreSQL but getting *error like ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"* please help me to solve this error
LINE 39:    SELECT random()*power( 10, 8 ) INTO STRICT W_OTPNUM;

```
BEGIN
              if p_mobile_no=usersdefotp_mobile_no 
                then 
                P_OTP :='123456'
                else
                SELECT random()*power( 10, 8 ) INTO STRICT W_OTPNUM;
                P_OTP :=LPAD(W_OTPNUM::TEXT, 6, '0');
                INSERT INTO usersdefotp(P_OTP)
                end if
        EXCEPTION
           WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
              P_OTP := NULL;
          END;
```

Comment: how is java involved here?

Comment: it don't involve java, only PLSQL and PostgreSQL

Comment: Must be me, but I do see a tag called "Oracle". so what is it?

Comment: By the way, for PostgreSQL, an ; is missing: P_OTP :='123456'; but there is more code that won't work, like the INSERT.

Comment: If you want to write an anonymous PL/pgSQL block, you need to use [`DO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html)

Comment: Apart from the errors that Frank already pointed out, the line `SELECT random()*power( 10, 8 ) INTO STRICT W_OTPNUM;` can be simplified to `w_otpnum := random()*power( 10, 8 );`

Comment: sir that issue is resolved i had wrote wrong syntax for insert

Comment: A simple SELECT statement within the INSERT, could replace all code. No plpgsql needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [declarations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-declarations.html) in a Procedure as an [Array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) on PostgreSQL, like this one:

```
do $$
declare
   randoms text[];
begin
  -- store data
  randoms = ARRAY(SELECT random()*power( 10, 8 ) INTO STRICT W_OTPNUM;
                P_OTP :=LPAD(W_OTPNUM::TEXT, 6, '0'));

   if something
   then
     do something
   else
     return format("%s", randoms)
   end if;
end   
$$;
```

That way you can store your select and then use him when needed to return;